# Hiding a post when three different users click on a button AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I need to hide a post when three different users click the same button. But I have no idea how I need to do this. It's like when you see a post on instagram and you want to mark it as inappropriate.
If someone knows how to do this. Please reply.

AJAX

```
$(".inap").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "delete.ajax.php",
            method: "GET", 
            data: { "post_id": $(this).data("post_id") },
            dataType: "html"

        }).done(function( res ) {
            console.log( "Data Hidden: " + res.status );
        }).fail(function(res)  {
            console.log("Sorry. Ajax failed ");
        }); 
    });
```

DELETE

```
include_once('db.php');
$conn = Db::getInstance();
if (!empty($_GET["post_id"])) {
    $post_id = $_GET["post_id"];

    $stm = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_id = :post_id");
    $stm->bindValue(":post_id", $post_id);
    $stm->execute();
    $result = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;

    } else {
        echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
    }
```

Comment: You could add a flag in your posts table by default at 0, increment it by one everytime someone clicks on your button and then add AND flag>2 to your delete statement.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a new integer column to your Post schema to count downvotes or "hide" clicks.
2. Send an increment-hide-click event to your PHP code with the id of the associated Post.
3. When rendering Posts (and deciding whether a particular Post should be rendered), compare the Post's hide-click-count field to your threshold (3).